# JTextPane undo and redo whole words

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I used the [UndoManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547404/1369488) to add undo and redo functionality to my JTextPane. However, it saves the text every time text is entered, so it undos to the last letter. How can I make it undo to the last word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_undo_edits.html That's an example of such merging edits.

Comment: Thanks! Your website is great, by the way.

Comment: One problem... when the user highlights something and deletes, this happens: `javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid location
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.getChars(GapContent.java:172)
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.getString(GapContent.java:150)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.getText(AbstractDocument.java:757)
 at UndoManager.undoableEditHappened(UndoManager.java:24)` and so on.

Comment: And it only happens when the user highlights and deletes something near the beginning or the end of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`UndoableEdit#addEdit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoableEdit.html#addEdit%28javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit%29). If you make non-whitespace edits stick together on the undo stack (by absorbing each other through this method) and whitespace edits too, then the next undo will act on the last work or last whitespace gap, which is what you want.